# How can I download this video? Not working for realplayer download

Tags: video, download, ftp, html, iframe

From the following webpage:

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/cpu-caches-and-why-you-care

I would like to download the video. I checked the HTML source code and the URL appears to be:

http://player.vimeo.com/video/22475694

is there any way I can download this? All my attempts have failed

Answer (score 1):

Had to begin playing the video before I could save it!